# android app crashed on my devise nexus 4 android 5.0 You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, devise, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

i created a android project with blank activity created with fragment and with **minSdkVersion 10** and **targetSdkVersion 21** when i run my app on my devise **nexus 4 android 5.0** the app crashed and i don't know why .

when i switch from **ActionBarActivity** to Activity the app work but i want create the app with  **ActionBarActivity** .

and logcat give me this error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rhanem.android.forecast.app/com.rhanem.android.forecast.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

she give me this message in logcat

```
Process: com.rhanem.android.forecast.app, PID: 3644
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rhanem.android.forecast.app/com.rhanem.android.forecast.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.rhanem.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

please help my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Manifest file specify Theme.AppCompat theme (or it's descendant) for your Activity.
`android:theme="Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: logcat give me that error Unable to start activity   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Comment: When do you encounter this Exception? I need more details.